# Reading this JSON array

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to read from this: http://api01.notaion.com/?item&id=120001462

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON('http://api01.notaion.com/?item&id=120001462', function(data) {

    });
</script>
```

I'm not sure if I need to use callback=?, neither how exactly to deal with the data. Hell I might be even mistaken somewhere else. Help.

Comment: What's the problem? Is `data` empty? What isn't working?

Comment: Blocked by **same origin policy** -> http://jsfiddle.net/vSf8S/

Answer (score 1):

The API doesn't seem to support CORS. However they do support JSONP:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://api01.notaion.com/?item&id=120001462',
    dataType: 'jsonp'
})
.success(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/h4shZ/

Answer (score 1):

Because you want to fetch the data from a different domain, you need to use jsonp, which is automatically done by jquery when you add callback=? to the url. So you get the following result:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON('http://api01.notaion.com/?item&id=120001462&callback=?', function(data) {   
           console.log(data);
           console.log(data.item[0].itemId); #prints 120001462
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this needs to use a `JSONP` call, which using vanilla JavaScript would be like this:

```
//create a global callback function
function jsonpCallback(jsonObject){

}
function getJSONP(){
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'http://api01.notaion.com/?item&id=120001462&callback=jsonpCallback';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

then as soon as it is called your callback would get the data from the server.